# jQuery just does not work anymore (on my site)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I've got a tiny simple jquery going on here where a div will slide down just a bit. But NOTHING in the jquery file works:

```
$('.starterLink').click(function(){
    $('.starterSummary').animate({'width': '230px'});
      });    
});
```

However, I have a different website with the exact same code, and that one works! Bu I need it to work on this one. Any suggestions? Can you see anything wrong here?

html:

```
<div class="packages">
    <div class="starter">
        <span><a href="@Href("#")" class="starterLink"><h1 class="starterLink">Starter Pack</h1></a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="business">
        <span><h1>Business</h1></span>
    </div>
    <div class="corporate">
        <span><h1>Corporate</h1></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="packageSummaries">
    <div class="starterSummary">
        <h1>Free Advertising</h1>
        <p></p>
        <a href="" class="roundedButton silver">Service Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="businessSummary">
        <h1></h1>
        <p>Service summary</p>
        <a href="" class="roundedButton silver">Service Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="corporateSummary">
        <h1>Service Heading</h1>
        <p>Service summary</p>
        <a href="" class="roundedButton silver">Service Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.packages {
    width: 60%;
    background-image: url('../Images/pres-bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    float: left;
}
.packageSummaries {
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
}
.starter {
    position: relative;
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    height: 140px;
    overflow: hidden;

    background-color: #02A7FF;
    opacity: .7;
}
.starter span {
  position: absolute;    
  bottom: 0;    
  right: 0; 
}
.business {
    position: relative;
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    height: 140px;
    overflow: hidden;

    background-color: #FF7402;
    opacity: .7;
}
.business span {
  position: absolute;    
  bottom: 0;    
  right: 0; 
}

.corporate {
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    height: 140px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #111111;
    opacity: .7;
}
.corporate span {
  position: absolute;    
  bottom: 0;    
  right: 0; 
}
.starterSummary {
    padding-left: 8px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 0px;
    background-color: Blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.businessSummary {
    padding-left: 8px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.corporateSummary {
    padding-left: 8px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

Any help at all is greatly appreciated. This has got me stumped.

Thank you

Comment: Is your browser showing any javascript errors? This is usually the first place to look. Check via Inspect Element in Chrome or the Firebug extension in Firefox.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. There are no errors. None at all.

Comment: Are you able to run any jQuery using the javascript console?

Comment: When you are working on the DOM, is it ready? Have you tried putting your code inside $().ready(function() { // your code } )

Comment: Yeah, it's ready, I do have the code inside the ready function. I can now see errors (after enabling them in IE, I didn't know they were disabled): It says $ - is undefined, and points to the $ at the start of the document ready function

Comment: if $ is undefined then the library is not loaded. check the path of jquery or see my answer. And use a decent browser for debugging.

Comment: Thank you all for youe help and answers. I managed to get it all working by downloading a new copy of the jQuery file and replacing my existing one with it. I figured since the exact same code was working on another site, maybe there's something wrong with the jquery file that i copied over. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have a }); to much in your jQuery. You should consider checking the errorconsole in the browser you're using. It would probably display that error.

```
$('.starterLink').click(function(){
    $('.starterSummary').animate({'width': '230px'});
      });    
});
```

**UPDATE**

It could also be because you're missing the reference to jquery.js. Check that it's included as a script-tag and that the URL is correct.

Comment: I tried your code anyway, still same problem. It says: "$ is undefined." And always points to the very first instance of $

Comment: That sound like you're missing the reference to jquery.js. Check that it's included as a script-tag and that the URL is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is not present you should get an error.
Try to type $ on the browser console and see if you get back the jQuery object.

Try to load jquery from Google or other CDN.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: what is a Cufon? is this? http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/ . Then search for jQuery noConflict Mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your script:

```
$('.starterLink').click(function(){
    $('.starterSummary').animate({'width': '230px'});
    // -->  });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="@Href("#")"..>
```

The quotes are wrong.

Try w3 validator and jslint to see if everything is valid.
Also a link to the actual site would help if it's possible.

Comment: The quote are fine. Anyway, I tried @3nigma's solution anyway and it doesn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple syntax error with a `});` that shouldn't be there.

```
$('.starterLink').click(function(){
    $('.starterSummary').animate({'width': '230px'});    
});
```

If you have an error in your code then none of the Javascript will work.

You can usually track down the issue using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (if you're using Firefox), or just your browser's developer console.

Answer (score 0):

unmatched braces `})` and what `href="@Href("#")"` means?

Comment: i think the OP is using RAZOR C#

Comment: @#nigma - You are correct. I am using Razor C#. @Emmerman, #Href("") is used by Razor. I am using WebMatrix.

Answer (score 0):

replace `href="@Href("#")"`  with `href="@Href('"'#'"')"`

here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wvaE3/2/)

you may not be able to see the animation because it'll try to navigate to the link, here you can see the animation http://jsfiddle.net/wvaE3/3/

Comment: I  will try that. I don't understand why though, because my other website with the exact same code still works.